# Cakephp 2.4 on PHP 7.3

Tags: php-5.6, cakephp-2.4, php-7.3

We have an application built and running on CakePHP V2.4. This is running on PHP V5.6. We would like to get this running on PHP V7.3.

Can you advise on how to do this and your experience with such a change.

Comment: I'd suggest you hire a programmer to do the upgrade for you. Seriously, have you tried anything? Your question is so open-ended that there's no reasonable answer imaginable. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome to Stack Overflow though!

Comment: this is  not a open ended question , I am 7 years experience php guy , I know cake completely I want to discuss different ways we can migrate to new framework which runs on php 7 or the same code to run on php 7.3 , this is technical problem facing , otherwise I have to put 200+ hours effort for recoding

Comment: I'm sorry if you took offense at what I wrote. The point I was trying to convey might be better explained by the links I gave though.

Comment: yeah I have checked the links , but I was looking for solutions or techniques anyone has developed

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp 2.4 doesn't support PHP 7. 
As per Cakephp 2 requirements:

> PHP 5.3.0 or greater (CakePHP version 2.6 and below support PHP 5.2.8
>   and above). CakePHP version 2.8.0 and above support PHP 7. To use PHP
>   above 7.1 you may need to install mcrypt via PECL. See Security for
>   more information.

So if you want to use PHP 7 then you have to use Cakephp 2.8 or greater version.
[Cakephp -> Installation -> Requirements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html)

Comment: Worth noting that if you're going to go from 2.4 to 2.6 you may as well go to 2.10 and take advantage of some of the other bug fixes and improvements, the upgrade path is pretty smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade your application to at least Cake 2.10. I believe that's compatible with PHP 7.2, anyway; not sure about 7.3. Migration guides for the various point releases are [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html).